# trying to use '#include <stdbool.h>' in VS 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use the stdbool.h library file in a C program. When I try to compile, however, an error message appears saying intellisense cannot open source file stdbool.h.

Can anyone please advise how I would get visual studio to recognise this? Is this header file even valid? I'm reading a book on learning C programming.

Comment: Apparently cold weather knows no bounds (i.e. it may have snowed in the netherworld), C99 support is finally starting with VS 2013, including stdbool.h.  [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx]

Comment: @AlexandreC.: hello from 2015! The latest VS has stdbool.h now! *chuckle*

Comment: I went ahead and used VS 2015 community edition as suggested by @Mints97. It solved my problem. When you open the VS 2010 project in VS 2015 it automatically asks for upgrade of compilers being targeted by the C/C++ project. Compilers in VS 2015 are targeting C99 hence it is able to locate the missing header files.

Answer (score 31):

```
typedef int bool;
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

works just fine. The Windows headers do the same thing. There's absolutely no reason to fret about the "wasted" memory expended by storing a two-bit value in an `int`.

As Alexandre mentioned in a comment, Microsoft's C compiler (bundled with Visual Studio) [doesn't support C99](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99132/c99-header-stdbool-h-missing) and likely isn't going to. It's unfortunate, because `stdbool.h` and many other far more useful features are supported in C99, but not in Visual Studio. It's stuck in the past, supporting only the older standard known as C89. I'm surprised you haven't run into a problem trying to define variables somewhere other than the beginning of a block. That bites me *every* time I write C code in VS.

One possible workaround is to configure Visual Studio to compile the code as C++. Then *almost* everything you read in the C99 book will work without the compiler choking. In C++, the type `bool` is built in (although it is a 1-byte type in C++ mode, rather than a 4-byte type like in C mode). To make this change, you can edit your project's compilation settings within the IDE, or you can simply rename the file to have a `cpp` extension (rather than `c`). VS will automatically set the compilation mode accordingly.

Modern versions of Visual Studio (2013 and later) offer improved support for C99, but it is still not complete. Honestly, the better solution if you're trying to learn C (and therefore C99 nowadays) is to just pick up a different compiler. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is a good option if you're running on Windows. Lots of people like the [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I've learned so much from just a few paragraphs! Thanks again! I'm going to try out the compilers you mentioned. Have a great Christmas!

Comment: This is a good and complete answer. regarding compiler, I used DevC++ and also Code::Blocks, none of them have proper intellisense and code coloring which makes it hard to read the c codes again. Although I don't like many of features that visual studio installs on your system by force and many bugs that still carried from version 2003 until now, it is still best in IDEs. Visual studio 2010 adds an ability to gray out the parts you put in `#ifdef` compiler directive which are not active. it is a lot helpful when you are tracking a compile bug

Comment: Here are the related bug reports on Connect: [773523](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773523/) and [748766](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748766/). Vote up so they might think about implementing C99 and C11 missing headers.

Comment: Note that in Visual C++'s C++ mode, `sizeof(bool) == 1`. If mixing C and C++ code, defining bool as int on the C side will cause funny issues with structures and bool arrays.

Comment: Note for the future: C99 and C++11 mode are only supported in Visual Studio 2013 and later. Attempting to compile anything that uses these on VS2012 or earlier **will not work**.

Comment: See [C99 library support in Visual Studio 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/)

Answer (score 13):

Create your own file to replace stdbool.h that looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#define false   0
#define true    1

#define bool int
```

In Visual Studio 2010 I had an issue using `typedef int bool;` as suggested elsewhere. IntelliSense complained about an "invalid combination of type specifiers." It seems that the name "bool" is still special, even though it's not defined.

Comment: I referenced this solution here: https://github.com/metabench/jsgui-node-png/issues/2
PDF archive:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgyzrx89w6g4oit/npm%20install%20jsgui-node-p...pdf

Comment: It is special for IntelliSense, because the front-end IntelliSense compiler is a C++ compiler. Specifically, in VS 2010, it is the EDG compiler. You can just ignore the IntelliSense warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a warning, on x64 platforms, VS2017 (I'm not sure about previous versions) defines `bool` as a value of 1 byte on C++ (e.g. a `char`). So this

```
typedef int bool;
```

could be really dangerous if you use it as an `int` (4 bytes) in C files and as a native `bool` in C++ (1 byte) (e.g. a `struct` in a `.h` might have different sizes depending if you compile it with C or C++).

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it is a real concern not only for structs but also if the C-function gets a pointer to bool (to set it), which will overwrite other variables etc.