# I need assistance with Strings in C

Tags: c, string, function

I'm new to the C language and I came across this question. Can anybody help me answer it.

Try to write a function which has two parameters that are both string type. the return value tells you whether the first string is sub-string of second parameter string or not

Comment: Obligatory: What have you tried? We can only help you help yourself, bro/sis.

Comment: To start you up:: Google strstr and its logic.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please put your efforts before asking the question.

Comment: Google/Bing is your assistant in learning about String.

Comment: Bing!? @UmerFarooq, we're here to help the guy/lady, and not put him in a worse position than when he/she started, bro. :P

Comment: LOL I see biasness in you. Seriously bro, it is a great Search engine. And it is improving every day, believe me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool contains_substring(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    if (strstr(str1, str2) != NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *str1 = "This is a test";//this is the string that you will be comparing against
    const char *str2 = "test";//this is the substring you're searching for.
    if (!contains_substring(str1, str2)) {
        printf("No match found!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("String 1 contains String 2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: because this example uses stdbool for the bool type, this example will have to be compiled with the C99 option `-std=c99` with gcc or a related compiler like clang, like this:

`gcc inputfile.c -std=c99 -o outputbinaryfilename`

Of course, you can circumvent including that library and using an additional compiler option entirely by defining bool as the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549206/866930)):

```
typedef int bool;
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

REFERENCE
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr

Comment: I had to change the program a bit to allow me to enter the text i want. is this still correct?

Comment: @Kaylo17: As far as I know, yes. What I mean is that I haven't updated it since you last commented. So, if it worked for you then, it should work for you now, as I haven't touched it since. ;)

Comment: I meant to attach my code, but I pressed enter before i could paste it. my bad. still not used to Stackoverflow's layout

Comment: contains_substring(char* str1, char* str2) {
        if (strstr(str1, str2) != NULL) {
            return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
        }
}

Comment: @Kaylo17: is that the code you've updated? If so, then that's perfectly fine. It should work. Compile it, run it, test it and see.

Comment: that's the function, and this is the implementation

int main() {
    char* str1;// this is the substring you're searching for.
    str1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    char* str2;// this is the string that you will be comparing against
    str2 = malloc(sizeof(char)* 1000);
    printf("Enter the first String\n");
    gets(str1);
    printf("Enter the second String\n");
    gets(str2);

    if (contains_substring(str1, str2)) {
        printf("No match found!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("String 1 is a substring of String 2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Kaylo17, one recommendation that I didn't catch before: use `contains_substring(const char *str1, const char *str2)` instead. This protects your strings from possible modification and avoid possible runtime problems. Plus, `strstr` takes `const char *` as the CString parameters. Just a suggestion. ;)

Comment: @Kaylo17: also, change this: `if (contains_substring(str1, str2))` to this: `if (!contains_substring(str1, str2))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. you've been loads of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unoptimized strstr

```
char *strstr(char *haystack, char *needle){
if (!needle[0]) return haystack;
unsigned int i;
while (*haystack){
  while (haystack[0]!=needle[0])haystack++;
  i=1;
  while (haystack[i] && needle[i] && haystack[i]==needle[i++]);
  if (!needle[i]) return haystack;
  else haystack+=i;
}
return haystack;
}
```

or an optimized version:
http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strstr.c

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the function strstr for finding substrings in c language. For example-

```
char s1[] ="hello world";
char * s2;
s2 = strstr (str,"world");  // s2 will be null pointer if it is not the substring
                            // else s2 will point to first occurrence of substring
if(!s2)
   // return true
else
   // return false
```

You should try to figure out how to pass strings to function by yourself :)