# Python 2.7.9 install esmre with error 'cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

I am using Windows 8 and Python 2.7.9. I tried to install `esmre` with `pip`, but have the following error:

> src/aho_corasick.c(48) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'stdbool .h': No such file or directory   error: command
>   'C:\Users\CHALLEN QU\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Micro
>   soft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit
>   status 2
>
> Failed building wheel for esmre
>   Failed to build esmre

---

Things I have already tried:

1. Reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7
2. Upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`
3. Look for a compiled version of `esmre`, which I have not found
4. Install `esmre` with `easy_install` or the setup.py inside the package.

It seems that I just can't compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"stdbool.h" is not a C++ header and Visual 2010 [doesn't support C99](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99132/c99-header-stdbool-h-missing).

As a workaround you could locate Visual's "include" directory and add "stdbool.h" file with the following contents:

```
typedef int bool;
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549206/2642204) or

```
#pragma once

#define false   0
#define true    1

#define bool int
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405759/2642204).

Another workaround in the linked thread is to use a different compiler.