# Install pylibmc on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, package, pylibmc

installing pylibmc for python in Windows. I am running pip install pylibmc, however, it's giving me this error:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\B
IN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2.7.9 install esmre with error 'cl.exe' failed with exit status 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071929/python-2-7-9-install-esmre-with-error-cl-exe-failed-with-exit-status-2)

Comment: Searching SO for 'visual c exit status 2' returns 163 hits.  I suspect your answer is among them.  You might also share that message with the author of pylibmc as something is wrong either with the upload or pip.

Comment: I tried adding stdbool.h in Visual studio->VC->include. Still getting the same error

Comment: I will check searching for visual C exit status 2. Thanks

Comment: @sundevil, have you fixed the issue? I am using python 3.6 on Windows 10 and got the same issue. I hope you would like to give me a hand.