# How to change compiler for header to C compiler (not C++) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For example i have

**myheader.h**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

_Bool foo()
{
    return true;
}
```

For cpp files i can just change `*.cpp` to `*.c`

But how to change compiler for **header file** to **C compiler** in **Visual Studio 2015**?

Comment: compile header file?

Comment: I use this file in main.c - #include "myheader.h" But i have error: identifier "_Bool" is undefined

Comment: Your C compiler doesn't seem to implement `_Bool`. It might be possible to enable that feature. But we can't help you since you didn't mention the used compiler which apparently isn't the one by Microsoft.

Comment: @cremno my compiler is msvcp140, Visual Studio 2015 (v140)

Comment: I have the free edition of that, which includes `stdbool.h`. I can use the type `_Bool` fine in C code. Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: @DmitryScaletta: No, it obviously isn't. Otherwise `_Bool` wouldn't be missing and you would also get a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

"stdbool.h" is a C99 header file. <strike>Microsoft's C/C++ compiler doesn't support it, and probably never will.</strike> MSVC 2013 and above have C99 support it seems. My bad.

You can:

1. Find another compiler
2. Use the hack:

   `typedef int bool;`
   `#define false 0`
   `#define true 1`
3. Switch to C++, which has a native `bool` type.

I personally recommend the third.

---

More reading on the topic here: [trying to use '#include <stdbool.h>' in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548521/trying-to-use-include-stdbool-h-in-vs-2010)

Comment: OP is using MSVC 2015, and saying "use a different language" is not an answer.

Comment: Ohh my bad. Looks like MSVC >= 2013 has C99 support.

Comment: @Quirk But if i try to use "stdbool.h" in my *.c files, all works fine.

Comment: @DmitryScaletta Have you tried using just `bool` instead of `_Bool` and not including `<stdbool.h>`?

Comment: @Quirk I don't know why, but if i using `bool` and including `<stdbool.h>` all works fine. If not including - not works.

Comment: The built-in type is `_Bool` so you can use that without including the header. But `bool` and `true` and `false` are `#define`d in `stdbool.h`.

Comment: From what I hear, it only got partial C99 support. (It is not a conforming compiler anyhow, so who including Microsoft cares)