# VS2019 - stdbool.h include is disabled when surrounded by stdio.h includes

Tags: c, header-files

I discovered this by accident when making some code changes.  I am using VS2019 Community with the latest updates as of 10/30/2020.  The following do-nothing code is in a .c file and both Intellisense and the compiler claim that 'identifier "bool" is undefined'.  The problem goes away if either of the stdio.h inclusions is removed or the stdbool.h inclusion is not sandwiched between them.

Obviously there is no reason to have both stdio.h inclusions but I had thought that header files were required to be designed such that they could be included in any order and such that multiple inclusions would have no detrimental effects.  I haven't examined the contents of the headers simply because that seemed irrelevant to whether this behavior violates the standards in some way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   bool b;
}
```

Comment: Why did you include "stdio.h" twice? Have you tried to include "stdbool.h" before "stdio.h"?

Comment: I thought they fixed [that header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918363/how-to-change-compiler-for-header-to-c-compiler-not-c-in-visual-studio-2015). Are you compiling with `/std:c11` or `/std:c17`?

Comment: @Akib - stdio.h was included twice by accident.  As I said in my posting, the problem goes away if either of the stdio.h is removed or if stdbool.h is not between two of them. My question here is not how to get it to work, but whether this is a bug or a feature in VS.

Comment: @Bob - In the project preferences I couldn't find any option to select the C language standard - Only C++14 and C++17 and default.  I tried the two options you suggest directly on the command line but it reported both as invalid.

Comment: I see. Maybe you have to update the SDK and the runtime too: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/

Comment: @dxiv - I will have to admit cockpit error on part of this because I had another file with a main function in the project I forgot to remove.  After fixing that the compile (and link) errors stopped, but Intellisense still puts its red squiggly under bool and everything associated with it and states that 'identifier "bool" is undefined'.  I then created an entirely new solution, project, and implementation file.  Although it still compiles and links correctly, the Intellisense issue is still present. Maybe Intellisense is confused by the header files.  Do you see the Intellisense issue too?

Comment: @BenevolentDeity I can confirm the Intellisense issue, though it is intermittent and the "*undefined*" squiggle would sometimes go away after un/commenting header includes, and not come back even after returning to the original code. Reminds me why I am not a big fan of Intellisense ;-)